# Cerrar página actual en Typescript

Tags: ionic, typescript

Estoy haciendo una App en Ionic.

En un momento de la App necesito pulsar un botón y cerrar la página actual en la que me encuentro.

Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

- Así declaro el botón en la vista HTML:

```html
<button ion-button full (click)="guardarNuevoPerfil()">Guardar Perfil</button>
```

y este es el método guardarNuevoPerfil() de la parte de Typescript:

```
this.storage.get('listadoPerfiles').then((perfiles) => {
    //Aquí guardo el perfil, justo despues necesito cerrar la página actual

    window.close();  //No funciona
    self.close();    //No funciona
});
```

Como se ve en el código, he intentado con window.close() y con seslf.close() pero no hace nada, no me cierra la pestaña.

Este es el comportamiento que quiero tener:

[image: comportamiento deseado]

He buscado en google y no me ha salido nada, prácticamente todo lo que sale en para Javascript.

Comment: Con cerrar la página te refieres a cerrar lo que esta viendo el usuario en ese momento, pero una vez que cierras que vas a mostrar? El home ?

Comment: Como digo es una app en ionic en la cual vas avanzando por pantallas hasta que llegas a esta. Una vez que pulsas el botón, se tiene que cerrar la actual y volver a la anterior

Comment: Puedes mostrar el constructor o decirme si recibes como parametro un NavController enel constructor

Comment: si, tengo una varaiable del tipo NavController llamada navCtrl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te respondo por aqui.
El constructor de tu page tiene que tener algo similar a esto:

```
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ){
   }
```

Por lo que si quieres salir de la página actual e ir a la anterior tienes que hacer esto:

```
this.storage.get('listadoPerfiles').then((perfiles) => {
    //Aquí guardo el perfil, justo despues necesito cerrar la página actual    
    this.navCtrl.pop();
});
```

Puedes revisar los metodos de NavController aquí:

[Descripción de las funciones de NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)